# java lottery program a little stuck

Tags: java, swing

Before posting this, i did check to see if there were similar programmes but couldnt find any similar to what im creating.

I am on the verge of ripping my hair out on completing the GUI aspects of my program. What i am struggling with and have been trying to complete for the past 2 days is to create a lottery program and within the class should displays a logo, a button and a text box to contain six numbers. The numbers should only be generated when the button is pressed.

I have already done the functions for the program, but have struggled with the GUI aspect as I havent been taught it very well by my lecturer.

Any help would be much appreciated as i am still a newbie when it comes to programming.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.*;

public class LotteryNumbers extends JFrame

{       
        int[] LotteryNumbers = new int[49];
        int i;
        Random rgen = new Random();  

        //Creating an Array of 50 integers
        public void createNumbers()  
        {
            for (i=0; i < LotteryNumbers.length; i++) 
            {   
                LotteryNumbers[i] = i + 1;
            }
        }

        //Shuffling the numbers in the array
        public void shuffleNumbers()
        {
            for (int j=0; j < LotteryNumbers.length; i++) 
            {
                int randomPosition = rgen.nextInt(LotteryNumbers.length);
                int temp = LotteryNumbers[j];
                LotteryNumbers[j] = LotteryNumbers[randomPosition];
                LotteryNumbers[randomPosition] = temp;
            }
        }

        //Sorting the numbers in the array
        public void sortNumbers()
        {
            for(int i=0; i < LotteryNumbers.length-1; i++) 
            {
                for(int j=0; j < LotteryNumbers.length-1-i; j++) 
                {
                    if(LotteryNumbers[j] > LotteryNumbers[j+1]) 
                    {
                        int temp = LotteryNumbers[j];
                        LotteryNumbers[j] = LotteryNumbers[j+1];
                        LotteryNumbers[j+1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Printing the numbers out
        public int[] printnumbers( int j, int [] LotteryNumbers)
        {
            for (j = 0; j<= 6 && j >= 1; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("Lotto number: " + j + ":" + LotteryNumbers);
            }

        return LotteryNumbers;
        }
```

}

Comment: Which part of your program is making trouble?

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: adding the components to make it a gui is the most difficult bit im having at the moment

Comment: lots of compile errors, starting with `JLablel`

Comment: in addition to JLabel  objects .... make your class extend JFrame

Comment: Also: please post working code; you make it very hard for others to answer your question when they can't run it themselves. As a start, make sure **it compiles without errors or warnings**.

Comment: class declaration should be `public class LotteryNumbers extends JFrame`

Comment: only once i added the JLabels did it give errors, if i removed that bit of the code, the functions compiles without any warnings

Comment: I'd start with a pen and paper, layout what it is you want to achieve. I'd also have a look at the [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: i know what i want to achieve, its just implementing the GUI coding that im having difficulty with. Its possible to combine the GUI code and the functions together as a few of my friends already did so on theirs. My lecturer hasnt explained this very well to me but il keep at it.

Comment: @jib123 Yes it's possible, not it's not recommended.  You have a good bases for a model, I'd keep the logic seperate

Answer (score 2):

You must make your

```
public class LotteryNumbers {
```

extend `JFrame` as follows

```
public class LotteryNumbers extends JFrame {
```

---

Also, I recommend you use some IDE (like Eclipse, Netbeans), if are not doing so already.

Comment: I have never used bluej. But it should be fine, just want to make sure that your using one.

Comment: i think its for educational environments but it is an IDE. Ive re-updated the code with the compiling version without errors. The problem i have is adding GUI to this code.

Comment: You had all the GUI related code already. Creating a GUI is fairly complicated. You should try to avoid mixing your application logic with GUI code. I would recommend you write a separate class that only handle the GUI first. That should make it easier.

Comment: You don't need to, nor should rarely have to extent a top level container such as JFrame, better to extend from something like JPanel and it to a frame - IMHO

Comment: That suggestion was based on the code before the edit. Now everything is gone, that's why it look irrelevant, you check the edit.